# What is the limit of the derivative of the harmonic extension/Dirichlet solution in $C^{1,\alpha}$ cases?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, laplacian, elliptic-pde

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ be an orientation-preserving homeomorphism. Denote by $H(f)$ the complex harmonic extension/solution in $\mathbb{D}$ to the Dirichlet problem with boundary data $f$, which can also be shown to be a homeomorphism of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ [Choquet's theorem].

Now,it follows from a well-known theorem of Kellog-Warschowski that if $f\in C^{k,\alpha}(\mathbb{S^1})$, then $H(f) \in C^{k,\alpha}(\mathbb{D})$.

My question is : assuming $k=1$, what is the limiting matrix of the (total) derivative matrix $DH(f)_p$ as $p\to \zeta \in \mathbb{S^1},p \in \mathbb{D}$ ? From some other kind of extensions I have seen before, I would take a guess that  $DH(f)_p \to f'(\zeta).Id$ as $p\to \zeta$, where $Id$ denotes the $2$ by $2$ identity matrix.

A reference to your answer will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is wrong. Take real $f$, for example, then harmonic extension is also real,
and its derivative is singular.
In general, I do not expect a simple answer. And certainly the answer cannot depend on the
local properties of $f$ near $\zeta$ only.
Indeed, leave $f$ unchanged on one half of the circle, but change it on another half.
It is clear that the derivative at the points of the first half will change.
So the limit of the derivative at a point cannot be computed from the knowledge of f only near this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I needed to change the question to suit the particular cases that is required for me. I know other type of extensions (not harmonic extension) where the limit depends on $\zeta$ only.Do you think in my modified question, there is a chance that the limit should be as I mentioned ?

Comment: Where is your modified question? I don't see it. What kind of extension do you want to consider now?

Comment: The modified question is : $f:S^1\to S^1$ is now a $C^{1,\alpha}$ diffemorphism. I am still considering its complex harmonic extension $H(f)$ and am asking whether $DH(f)_p \to f'(\zeta).Id$ as $p \to \zeta, p \in \mathbb{D}, \zeta \in S^1$ ?

Comment: The other extension I am talking about comes from theory of Riemann surfaces, where there is a particular kind of extension called Douady-Earle extension $F(f)$ where $DF(f)_p \to f'(\zeta)$ as $p \to \zeta$, where $f$ is a $C^{1,\alpha}$ circle diffeomorphims (actually $C^1$ suffices.

Comment: What is the difference between the "modified question" and
the original question? I don't see any. 

Comment: The previous question was $f:S^1\to C$,and this function was any $C^{1,\alpha}$  function on $S^1$, and in answering, you chose the particular case where $f:S^1\to R$. I changed the question to where $f:S^1\to S^1$ is any orientation-preserving $C^{1,\alpha}$ diffeomorphism of $S^1$, so we cannot consider $f:S^1\to R$ anymore. Does that seem clear ? Thanks.

Comment: But this is the same thing: changing your homeomorphism near the
point -1, for example will change the derivative of the harmonic extension near 1.
The derivative of the harmonic extension near a point
does not only depend on your boundary function near this point,
but depends on the whole boundary function.
So you cannot possibly hope for anything like
$DH(f)\to f'.Id$.
